# How to add custom widgets as markers in Flutter MapboxGL?

Tags: flutter, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

Is there a way to add custom Flutter widgets as markers to the Mapbox MapView on Flutter? For example, markers as shown in the below image.

I have looked through tickets regarding Mapbox on both StackOverflow and Github but couldn't find any luck. The relevant component I found is the Symbol but it doesn't seem to support custom widget or custom photo.

Thanks!

[Custom markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTq8u.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing. Unfortunately, it seems that the only option is to use flutter_map, an other plug in that is less efficient with Mapbox...